# ComboBox binding to select item based on equality of properties of two sources when using datatemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, datatemplate

**Please note:**

- The two types in the lists are simplified a lot for this example and must be kept separate.
- The use of an int as connection between the types can not be changed.

**The problem:**

Given the code below, how do I get the ComboBox marked with `???` to:

- Display the `ColorDefs.Name` as its content.
- Set `SelectedItem` to the one where `Models.DisplayColorNumber` is equal to `ColorDefs.ColorNumber`.
- Update the `Models.DisplayColorNumber` updated if the selection is changed.

**In code-behind**

```
public List<ModelData> Models { get; }
public List<DisplayColorDefinition> ColorDefs { get; }

DataContext=this;
```

**XAML:**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Models}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ComboBox ??? />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Models, Path=Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**ModelData type:**

```
public class ModelData
{
    private string name;
    private int displayColorNumber;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    public int DisplayColorNumber
    {
        get { return displayColorNumber; }
        set { displayColorNumber = value; }
    }
}
```

**DisplayColorDefinition type:**

```
public class DisplayColorDefinition
{
    private int colorNumber;
    private string name;
    private Color displayColor;

    public int ColorNumber
    {
        get { return colorNumber; }
        set { colorNumber= value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public Color DisplayColor
    {
        get { return displayColor; }
        set { displayColor = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't build. I don't understand this. How come the backing field `private int colorNumber` is used for the `public string ColorNumber` property?? `int` cannot be implicitly converted to/from `string`.

Comment: Oops, a typo. It's corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath :

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Models}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.ColorDefs, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                            DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                            SelectedValue="{Binding Path=DisplayColorNumber}"
                            SelectedValuePath="ColorNumber"
                            />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayColorNumber}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

SelectedValue will be the property on the Model object, and SelectedValuePath will indicate which property of the DisplayColorDefinition to use for the binding.